# Transferring data from one table to another using a where clause mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I would like to copy data from one table to another, but placing it in a specific row. The variable is set, the tables and query are named correctly and the columns set up correctly.

I would like to select the data circled in black

[image]

and place it within the section circled below in black

[image]

The query I am using if below. When it runs without the WHERE clause it goes on the row below, when the WHERE clause is added it is blank.

```
$query = "INSERT INTO Results (Q1A) SELECT Q1AY FROM Answers WHERE User = $email";
```

Comment: If you want to add the result to an existing row you need to use update, not insert.

Comment: Would the update clause still be able to transfer the data from one table to another?

Comment: Is there any field/column is common in both Results and Answers table ?

Comment: @RajeshManilal not that i'm aware of. would this need to be set up in order to work?

Comment: @RajeshManilal thank you for your help. It's just weird how the data transfers across successfully without the WHERE clause.

Comment: @AlexProbert You need to update the existing record in Results table with the corresponding value from Answers table, right ? If YES, then we need a common field/column name in both table to do the process, so that it updates the correct record.

Comment: @RajeshManilal Thank you for your time and help, ill start to do some research into this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
$query ="UPDATE Results R SET Q1A= (SELECT Q1AY FROM Answers) WHERE R.User=$email"
```

This only works if there are only one row in Answers, but your code seems to assume as much.

Comment: Afraid this didn't work. I'm aiming to have multiple rows (basically in the end to various users to save their input), would having multiple rows impact this?

Comment: If you have multiple rows in the Answers table, you need to have a common field in them to join the tables on.

Comment: i'm afraid i'm not fully aware of having a common field, would this be needed in order to work?